# python read text file into array

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python to auto-parse a set of text files and turn them into XML files.

There are alot of people asking how to loop through a text file and read them into an array.  The trouble here is that this wont quite work for me.

I need to loop through the first three lines individually then drop the rest of the text file (body) into one array entry.

The text file is formatted as follows.

> Headline
>
> Subhead
>
> by A Person
>
> text file body content.  Multiple paragraphs

How would I go about setting up an array to do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with open("data1.txt") as f:
    head,sub,auth = [f.readline().strip() for i in range(3)]
    data=f.read()
    print head,sub,auth,data
```

If you've spaces between the the lines, then you should try:

`filter()` will remove he empty lines:

```
 with open("data1.txt") as f:
    head,sub,auth =filter(None,(f.readline().strip() for i in range(6)))
    data=f.read()
    print head,sub,auth,,data
```

Comment: @enrico.bacis just `strip()` is fine.

Comment: Wonderful this did it.  One more question how would I get the current path(where the text file lives) and append that to the bottom of the list?

Comment: @user1789778 if you're taking about the current working directory then try `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to put all the text except for the first 3 lines into an array (list). Here's how to do that:

```
with open("/path/to/your/file.txt") as f:
    all_lines = f.readlines()
content_lines = all_lines[3:]
content_text = '\n'.join(content_lines)
content_list.append(content_text)
```

**Explanation:** You first open the file, and then put all of its lines into a list. Then, you take all the lines after the first three, and put those into a list. Then, you join this new list with newlines to make it content again. Then, you append this new content to a list that you've created beforehand called `content_list`

---

If you want to put the first three lines into your list as well, then do the following before appending to `content_list`:

```
for line in all_lines[:3]:
    content_list.append(line)
```